# CollectionDataContract to be used to consume Json array

Tags: .net, json, wcf, datacontract

Suppose there is this json produced by a service:

```
[{"key1": 12, "key2": "ab"}, {"key1": 10, "key2": "bc"}]
```

is this possible to be retrieved by wcf rest and parsed using CollectionDataContract as a list then parsed again automatically with DataContract?

I tried doing so, but always giving 'root level is invalid, line 1,position 1'

Comment: Please show how you tried to parse it, it may be you are just slightly off and the extra eyes on here can show you the rest of the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about [CDC] and JSON - it should just work - see the code below. Try to compare it with yours, including the networking traces (as seen in a tool such as Fiddler) and see what is different.

```
public class StackOverflow_15343502
{
    const string JSON = "[{\"key1\": 12, \"key2\": \"ab\"}, {\"key1\": 10, \"key2\": \"bc\"}]";
    public class MyDC
    {
        public int key1 { get; set; }
        public string key2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("[key1={0},key2={1}]", key1, key2);
        }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract]
    public class MyCDC : List<MyDC> { }

    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet]
        public Stream GetData()
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON));
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        MyCDC GetData();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new WebChannelFactory<ITest>(new Uri(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var result = proxy.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```